# Shell script - Is it possible to skip over a hanging process without sending it to background?

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell script to setup my environment, install dependencies, initialize a webserver, and launch a boilerplate in the browser.

My problem is that when it gets to the line where it initializes the webserver, it hangs (as it should) and will not execute the command on the next line to open the browser.

I understand I can send it to the background with `&`, and it will still send it's output to back to the terminal, but this is a bit inconvenient because then ctrl + c no longer works to kill the process, and I have to find and kill the process to get rid of it.

I have tried using the `fg` command after opening the browser, hoping it would send the process back to the foreground, but I get the following error: `fg: no job control`

Is throwing the process in the background the only way to tell the script "run the next line without waiting for current command to finish executing"?

Comment: yes, that's the only way. The shell waits for foreground processes to finish, it doesn't wait for background processes.

Comment: That's essentially the main difference between foreground and background.

Comment: Yea, I knew that, but I was just wondering if there was any way to override that behavior. I guess not. If fg was working, I wouldn't mind just doing that, but I can't get it working. When I type `jobs -l`, it returns nothing.

Comment: Server programs are usually intended to be run as daemons, not manually by users.

Comment: How are you running the script? If you want the processes to be created as children of your interactive shell, you have to source it. Otherwise it runs as a child process, and the programs it spawns are its children. Your interactive shell only manages its own children.

Comment: run your webserver in the background, and then sleep for X seconds, then test the websever logs for conditions that you want to handle? Otherwise, totally agree with Barmar. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
webserver &
ws=$!
browser 
kill $ws
```

The above is *pseudo-code*, but the idea should be clear.  Run the server in the background, save its *PID* to `$ws`,  then run the browser, and when that quits, `kill` the server.

Comment: Although I can see how that works, I don't want to kill the webserver process, because it needs to stay running.

Comment: @ElliotTregoning, Any number of commands can be inserted between the last two lines `browser` and `kill`.  Also storing the the *PID* in variable `$ws` makes it easier to control the server.  To put the server in the foreground, do `fg $ws`, to background it again, `bg $ws`.

Comment: fg is not working for me, as I said in my original post. When I type `jobs`, nothing shows up.